# How terraform handle nested structure in one state file

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I am a bit confused on how complex terraform folder structure would be managed in a single terraform state file.

Assuming I have the following structure:
[tf-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bTyA.png)

- *modules* folder is a reusable code.
- *backend-app* is not a module, but an actual resources which describe my backend "stuff".
- *frontend-app* is not a module, but an actual resources which describe my frontend "stuff".
- *root-infra* - let's assume I have additional folder called "root-infra" which is running all my VPC/gateway/network and some common infra stuff.

I can't understand how everything would be triggered to run in a single state file?

for example, if I add some resources in my backend-app, I would run plan/apply from backend-app folder, but this will result all my common infra + frontend be deleted.

So I'm assuming that even if I make a change in my backend-app folder, I still need to run plan/apply from my root-infra folder, assuming that the main.tf there include the backend-app (and also the frontend, etc.).

Am I right?
if so, how would I import my backend/frontend folders into my root-infra main.tf? and why is backend/frontend are any different from a regular module?

Answer (score 0):

From the structure you provided, it seems you should actually be having multiple state files - one for `root-infra`, one for `backend-app` and one for `frontend-app`.

Each of those directories' state file will then manage the resources located in them. Using one single state file like you mentioned (Assuming you're using a remote state here, as local state files would already solve that problem), means that when you run it in the `root-infra`, terraform 'thinks' that these are the only resources you're deploying.

Next, when you move to `backend-app` and try to deploy from there, but with the same state file used in `root-infra`, terraform doesn't see the `root-infra` resources anymore in this directory, but instead sees new `backend-app` resources. It will attempt to delete the `root-infra` resources and replace them with `backend-app` etc. The same thing will happen later when you're deploying `frontend-app`.

The only solution here is to have different state files managing unique stack of resources. `root-infra`, `backend-infra` and `frontend-infra` are each one stack which should be managed individually.

If you wanted to manage all of them from one single state file, your structure should change and the entire thing should be one or two stack max. One for infra, one for applications. As if you were deploying all resources from one single directory instead, and you could just identify the different apps individually by having different `tf` files in the same directory. E.g.:

```
tf/modules/network/dns.tf 
tf/modules/network/output.tf 
tf/modules/network/variables.tf

tf/infra/main_infra.tf
tf/infra/vars_infra.tf
tf/infra/infra_remote_state.tf

tf/apps/main_frontend.tf
tf/apps/main_backend.tf
tf/apps/apps_remote_state.tf
```

Comment: Well, infra has common resources that their IDs need to be used in backend/frontend, so I can't just managed infra in different state file (I can't use terraform_remote_state because it is not recommended and not a good practice due to security). in the other hand, backend/frontend are not related to each other but they both related to infra

Comment: OK got it. Sorry, maybe I'm not getting the right picture but infra resources while can be shared, they can still be separated in a different state file. Could you elaborate as to how you are using the state file right now with local state? Generally you would refer to resources in other directories using `data sources` block. Also when you say the remote state is not recommended or a good practice, are you referring to limitations in your organisation? Cause I've always known remote state to be the right approach, for collaboration, security, and proper backup/change history etc.